# How the shift function is working in below code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, quandl

Python Program : Here is a .shift function (df[fore].shift(-fore_out)).Can you explain what it is doing?

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import math
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
fore = 'Adj. Open'
df.fillna(-99999,inplace=True)
fore_out =math.ceil(0.1*len(df))
df['label'] = df[fore].shift(-fore_out)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: it's shifting the rows by 10% of the number of rows down, you could've read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift)

Answer (score 0):

shift function take as a parameter an int and is applied  to a series or dataframe. (in this case a series).

It will shift the values of that series/dataframe down or up (depending if negative or positive) by those many cells.

In that case specifically its creating a new column in the dataframe with the name "label" and giving it the value of the "ad. open" shifted by 10% of its length.

In case of trouble understanding its always helpfull to print out the result of the function or looking up its documentation before making a post about it.